# Returning all odd numbers in a nested list

Tags: python

Trying to return all odd numbers from a nested list using recursion. Not too sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
def return_odds(a):

    odd = []
    if isinstance(a, list):
        for item in a:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                return_odds(item)

            if isinstance(item, int):
                if item % 2 == 1:
                    odd.append(item)

    if isinstance(a, int):
        if a % 2 == 1:
            odd.append(a)
    return odd
```

Comment: Please give an example nested list, your desired output, correct your indentation, and indicate where you think you are stuck.

Comment: Please fix the indenting in your question.

Comment: `even_list.append(item)` what is `even_list` and why are you appending odd number to it?

Comment: `if item % 2 == 1:` is true for odd numbers, not even

Comment: It sounds like you want a recursive function to return all odd values from a list of nested lists?

Answer (score 1):

You're dropping the returned value from your recursion.

A typical recursive function looks something like this:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

In your example, when you recurse and call `return_odds(item)`, your not using the returned value. Try this instead:

```
def return_odds(a):
    odd = []
    if isinstance(a, list):
        for item in a:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                odd += return_odds(item)

            if isinstance(item, int):
                if item % 2 == 1:
                    even_list.append(item)

    if isinstance(a, int):
        if a % 2 == 1:
            odd.append(a)
    return odd
```

Note that the return value of `return_odds(item)` is appended to your `odd` list.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code.

### Your errors

First you throw away the return value of your recursive call. Instead, extend your list `odd` with the returned value.

```
return_odds(item)
# replace by: odd.extend(return_odds(item))
```

Second, you have a variable `even_list` that appears nowhere. You probably meant to use the existing list `odd`.

```
even_list.append(item)
# replace by: odd.append(item)
```

### Improvement

That being said, there is still a conceptual error in your code: *it will accept a single `int` and return it in a `list*`. This does not seem to be part of your requirements. Instead, loop though your input `a` and do a recursive call when encoutering a `list`.

```
def return_odds(a):
    odd_numbers = []
    for i in a:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            odd_numbers.extend(return_odds(i))
        elif isinstance(i, int) and i % 2:
            odd_numbers.append(i)
        # You might also want to determine the behaviour if i is not an int

    return odd_numbers
```

#### Example

```
print(return_odds([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]]))
```

#### Output

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I get this error. TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Are you trying to call return_odds(1) or something like that?